# How to get the average price I paid for the shares I own by trade history in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of my trade history in the stock market and I want to get the average price I paid for the shares I still own of specific stock.
Here's an example of the table:

| Date | Action | Symbol | Shares | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/06/2020 | BUY | GEM | 1000 | $100 |
| 23/06/2020 | SELL | GEM | 1000 | $5,000.00 |
| 23/06/2020 | BUY | GEM | 1000 | $50 |
| 23/06/2020 | BUY | GEM | 1000 | $40 |
| 23/06/2020 | BUY | GEM | 1000 | $30 |
| 23/06/2020 | BUY | AAPL | 60 | $140 |

The return of the formula should be 40 because I bought 1000 for 100 but I sold it so it shouldn't have impact on the average price. so basically it's (50 * 1000 + 40 * 1000 + 30 * 1000) / 3000 = 40

I tried using this solution [Get average stock price in Google Sheets from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188651/get-average-stock-price-in-google-sheets-from-a-list) by adjusting the formula to my situation like this:

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(FILTER(E2:E; B2:B="buy"; C2:C="GEM"); FILTER(D2:D; B2:B="buy"; C2:C="GEM"))
```

But the result is 55 which is wrong.

Comment: How to deal with scenarios of lets say 1. whats the ideal output if you sold partial shares (500) in row 2?  `OR` 2. your average price is 40 from rows 3,4,5 but now you added a sell of 10 shares (GEM) in the last row as new transaction?

Comment: 1. the avarage price should be the average price I paid for the shares. if I bought 1000 for 100$ and then sold some of it so it's pay per share would take a smaller part of the average price. the average price stay 100 at this point but its cut is the amount of shares I bought so far minus the amount of shares I sold at this point.
2. Yes if I sold 10 more shares so the average price wont change but the total I paid for the total shares would because the total is effected by selling because the amount of shares I own change. I hope its understandable if not please tell.

Comment: in your case (in 2.)the result should be:
(1000*30+
1000*40+
1000*50+
10*(the price I sold for))/3010

Comment: for first case it should be 500*100+1000*30+1000*40+1000*50/3500

Comment: your first case scenario(+numbers) makes total sense but not so much with the case 2 - you have included `sell` price value and shares (10) in the average formula while my thinking is just like the first case shouldn't the 10 shares be deducted from row 3 maybe and the formula becomes `(990*50 + 1000*40 + 1000*30)/2990`

Comment: @rockinfreakshow You're right I added instead of subtract it should be:
total shares I own: 1000+1000+1000-10 = 2990
total I paid: 1000*30+1000*40+1000*50-10*((1000*30+1000*40+1000*50)/3000)

Comment: I haven't come across this method of calculating average cost before - have heard of FIFO and LIFO https://www.warriortrading.com/lifo-vs-fifo-which-is-better-for-day-traders/ The trouble with it is that logically you would then dispose of 1/300 of the shares at each value i.e. 3.33 shares in each case leaving you with 996.67 of each which is a bit of a strange concept. As you can see, I have assumed one established method (FIFO) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to maintain a queue to implement this type of FIFO calculation, as I did in my answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351891/calculate-avg-price-realized-gain-unrealized-gain-via-udf-using-fifo-method) in Excel using VBA. This would be better done in GAS but for a modest number of shares you could try generating a row for each individual share and using a formula to maintain a sort of queue to which you either vstack more shares on the end when buying or use chooserow to remove them from the beginning when selling:

```
=average(reduce(,sequence(rows(tocol(A:A,1))-1),lambda(a,c,if(index(A2:A,c)="Buy",vstack(a,sequence(index(B2:B,c),1,index(C2:C,c),0)),chooserows(a,sequence(rows(a)-index(B2:B,c),1))))))
```

[image]

Then suppose you were to sell only 5 of the original shares:

[image]

which is the same as

```
=average.weighted({100,50,40,30},{5,10,10,10})
```

**EDIT**

Found an error (I should have been retaining the last n shares, not the first n, where n is the number of shares remaining after a sale) this is the updated version:

```
=average(reduce(,sequence(count(B:B)),
lambda(a,c,if(index(A2:A,c)="Buy",vstack(a,sequence(index(B2:B,c),1,index(C2:C,c),0))
,if(index(B2:B,c)=count(a),"",chooserows(a,1,sequence(count(a)-index(B2:B,c),1,index(B2:B,c)+2)))))))
```